# Angularfire-code in app fails after upgrade to firebase 3

Tags: angularjs, firebase, dependency-management, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I have a webapp that uses firebase 2.2.2. Now I went to firebase.com and had to move to a new version of Firebase. Then I get the instruction to put this code in the html-file of the app:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSakdsjfg-Lw.kadjfglkadjhgxhMDbq4",
    authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

but if I do so, and remove the existing reference:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
```

then the app doesn't work anymore. Specifically the angular-instructions don't seem to work anymore. In following code for instance the text is shown but the link to menu-item 'Factory-Service' doesn't work now.

```html
<div class="header" ng-controller="MenuCtrl as menuCtrl">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li ng-if="menuCtrl.isLoggedIn()"><a ng-href="#/buildings">Buildings</a></li>
    <li ng-if="menuCtrl.isLoggedIn()"><a ng-href="#/apartments">Apartments</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/factsvc">Factory-Service</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a ng-href="#/">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h3 class="text-muted">Hello AngularFire anonymous authentication</h3>
</div>
```

The app works with AngularJS and AngularFire-code:

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

If I install the latest version of Angular fire (npm install angularfire --latest) then a dependency to firebase version 2.4.2. is installed, not version 3.x. (when I run npm install firebase --latest however version 3.0.2 is installed).

How to solve this? Should I then not include the code Firebase tells me to include or can I make angularfire depend on firebase 3.x manually? Or leave the reference to v. 2.2.2. alongside the new reference?

Comment: Obviously, since the API has changed in breaking ways, you can't use the same lib without an update. You can follow the upgrade to AngularFire is in [this PR](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/pull/717)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the API changed in breaking ways between 2.x and 3.0, you won't be able to use AngularFire until the authors (me and others) upgrade the library. That is taking place in [this changelist](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/pull/717), which is nearly completed.

Comment: Hi Kato, can you please confirm angularfire now supports firebase v3  now? Please also can you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886396/simple-firebase-v3-data-retrieval-with-angularfire-v2